# How can I get my assertions in pytest to stop being abbreviated with ellipsis?

Tags: python, pytest

How can I get my assertions in pytest to stop being abbreviated with ellipsis ?

Every time I have an assertion that reports error it truncates all my strings with "..." why is that? how can I stop that?

Comment: `assert("a"*(10**6) == "a"*(10**6 - 1))`. Why do you not want truncation?

Comment: obviously i know why the values are truncated and the risk of not truncating. but it's greatly outweighing the fact that i have no idea what the test failure is when an assert is done between two larger strings.

Comment: See a simple hack here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171554/preventing-truncation-of-long-strings-in-pytest/60321834#60321834

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38009364/2809027) doesn't work in general.** In [our use case](https://github.com/beartype/beartype), for example, pytest truncates parameters passed to functions called from assertion statements:

```
E                   AssertionError: assert None is not None
E                    +  where None = search('\\n\\*\\s.*\\b[Tt]upla item 0\\b',
'@beartyped pep_hinted() parameter pep_hinted_param=((<function <lambda> at
0x7fe278838830>,),) violates PEP type hint...7fe278838830>,):\n  * Not int, bool, or
float.\n  * Tuple item 0 value <function <lambda> at 0x7fe278838830> not str.')

beartype_test/unit/pep/p484/test_p484.py:124: AssertionError
```

Note the ellipses (i.e., `...`) that pytest interjected without our permission between the substrings `violates PEP type hint` and `7fe278838830>,):\n` in the above output, replacing a mission-critical substring needed to make sense of that output.

Thanks, overly helpful pytest developers. You shouldn't have. <sup>**Really.**</sup>

### what's the problem, bruh?

To corroborate both [@NicholasDiPiazza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000993/how-can-i-get-my-assertions-in-pytest-to-stop-being-abbreviated-with-ellipsis#comment80824696_38009364) and [@MatthiasUrlichs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966179/matthias-urlichs), Pytest sadly ignores `-v` options when truncating parameters passed to functions called from assertion statements – which is more than mildly infuriating.

Pytest developers, if we ask for verbosity four friggin' times, it means: "Yes, we really do want verbosity, are well-apprised of the potential pitfalls, and could care less because uncensored error reporting is much more important than minimizing those nebulous theoretical harms that frankly don't apply to real-world continuous integration."

### what's the solution, bruh?

Our working solution is as follows:

- [Pass the `--showlocals` option to the `addopts` setting in the project's top-level `pytest.ini` file:](https://github.com/beartype/beartype/blob/3cffdc1512292d047c443b86713abc848e14bf16/pytest.ini#L76) e.g.,

```
addopts = -vvvv --showlocals -p no:xvfb -r a --doctest-glob=
```

- Assign the verbose string (or object representation, or *whatever*) being truncated to a local variable in the problematic test. In our use case, for example, we assign the verbose exception message being truncated to a local variable in that test: e.g.,

```
def test_problem_function():
    with raises(Exception) as exception_info:
        raise ValueError("a"*1024)

    exception_str = str(exception_info.value)   # <--- This is where the magic happens.
    assert problem_function("a"*1024, exception_str)

def problem_function(substr, bigstr):
    return substr not in bigstr
```

- Manually inspect pytest output for that variable's value instead: e.g.,

```
========================================================== FAILURES ===========================================================
______________________________________________ test_truncated_exception_message _______________________________________________

    def test_truncated_exception_message():
        with raises(Exception) as exception_info:
            raise ValueError("a"*1024)
    
        exception_str = str(exception_info.value)
>       assert problem_function("a"*1024, exception_str)
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = problem_function(('a' * 1024), 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')

exception_info = <ExceptionInfo ValueError('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa') tblen=1>
exception_str = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa'

beartype_test/unit/pep/p484/test_p484.py:39: AssertionError
```

While the `AssertionError` itself remains truncated, the `--showlocals` option correctly preserves the untruncated value of the local `exception_str` test variable. *Voilà!*

This actually works as advertised, with the caveat that this only works as advertised for strings (or object representations, or *whatever*) that are directly assignable to local variables in tests. That's typically but not always the case – which is why pytest *really* needs to start respecting `-vvvvvvvvvvvvvv` options in its error reporting.

Comment: The negative, emotional tone hinders the answer being easily understandable

Answer (score 3):

Could you show an example? This is how the output looks for me:

```
    def test_foo():
>       assert "a"*100 == "a"*100 + "b"
E       assert 'aaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaa' == 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaab'
E         Skipping 89 identical leading characters in diff, use -v to show
E         - aaaaaaaaaaa
E         + aaaaaaaaaaab
E         ?            +
```

I think the diff makes it perfectly clear what's failing - but with `-v` (as the message suggests) I get the full diff:

```
    def test_foo():
>       assert "a"*100 == "a"*100 + "b"
E       assert 'aaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaa' == 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaab'
E         - aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
E         + aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
E         ?
```

Comment: the answer must be the "-v" that you are adding. i'll look if we are adding that

Comment: Can you try with `-vvvv` and see what you get? that's what we use.

Comment: Same output with `-vvvv`.

Comment: i was going to go into the pytest code and find the abbrevation logic but i then decided to not care

Comment: I'd still appreciate simply seeing an example of an assertion where `-v` doesn't work, so I can at least open an issue, or fix it (I'm one of pytest's core developers)

Comment: Just had encountered this myself; my case was comparing if an object is in a list was of custom objects (in my case [mock.Call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.call) objects). Unpacking calls into tuples made ellipsis go away in `-v` mode.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Arguments are -sxvvvv. `async_fn = functools.partial(functools.partial(<function TestQos.test_basic_qos_default_args at 0x7f3e11f7ba60>, <bound method Te...t_basic.TestQos object at 0x7f3e13c019e8>>, amqp=<trio_amqp.tests.testcase.ProxyAmqpProtocol object at 0x7f3e1395c0f0>)` @NicholasDiPiazza

Comment: **This doesn't actually work.** To corroborate both @NicholasDiPiazza and @MatthiasUrlichs, Pytest sadly ignores `-v` options when truncating `AssertionError` output – which is more than mildly infuriating. Pytest developers, if I ask for verbosity *four* friggin' times, it means: "Yes, I really *do* want verbosity, am well-apprised of the potential pitfalls, and could care less because complete error reporting is vastly more important than minimizing those nebulous theoretical harms that frankly don't apply to real-world continuous integration."

Answer (score 0):

for me just adding below was sufficient.

`-vvvv`

good practice is to have your test runner script accept addition `@`

where you can pass additional flags such as above or `-k some_test_substring` as needed